# PHP loop through simple xml and strore value in an array as a string

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have a php function ($get_user_info) that returns an xml string. I'm trying to loop through the xml and add the value of $user->id to an array. This works but it adds $user->id to the array as an object. Is there any way to generate an array of values only. e.g. array(10,12,13,etc.)?

Here is some sample code that I'm using:

```
$users = simplexml_load_string($get_user_info);
$user_ids = array();
foreach ($users->user as $user) {
//echo "$user->id";       // this echoes the value which is what I want
$user_ids[] = $user->id;  // this adds an object to the array
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simple parsing to `string` ?

```
$user_ids[] = (string) $user->id;
```

or `int`

```
$user_ids[] = (int) $user->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the object to the primitive type you want

So

```
$user_ids[] = (int) $user->id;
```